# How to use VPN in a similar manner as SSH tunes?

Tags: ssh, vpn, cisco

In order to remotely access to an internal network, I am provided with a Cisco AnyConnect based VPN solution. I can successfully connect into the network, but since all my traffic is routed via this VPN, I am unable to access any other external pages while connected.

I also have access to a computer inside of this network. Previously this computer was directly accessible from external network, so I could make ssh tunnel to access to the services on that computer (it runs openssh server among others).

Which configuration would you recommend to use VPN only to access this computer? I want to avoid setting up a virtual machine only to have Cisco Anyconnect running within virtual system to access to the computer.